# Netcat and sharing images and html files on port 80

Tags: linux, networking, port

I am trying to setup a server to share single pictures and single html files using netcat. I have some questions about the netcat server.

If I setup the server to listen on port 80, the port 80 shows as listening using nmap.

I did this by using the command:

```
nc -l -p 80
```

on Linux

and then I ran a nmap scan using the command; with the IP address of the Linux machine:

```
nmap 192.168.88.221
```

I can see that it is listening on port 80 now

[image: Netcat listening on port 80 and Nmap Scan to show its listening on port 80]

To exit the `nc` command I have to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sometimes the host key is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> for VirtualBox so you might have to use the other <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

Now I want to share a file that is on the root user desktop so I use the 
command:

```
nc -lvp 80 < Heart.jpg
```

and it says. No such file or directory.

[image: No such file or Directory]

The file is saved on the desktop and the user I am using is root and password

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get it working?

Comment: Your image file isn't in your present working directory, so either change directory beforehand or specify the full path to the file in your netcat command.

Comment: I thought since I am using root it is the default directory (the desktop)? Can you please show examples of how I can do this with either changing the directory or the command?

Comment: `nc -lvp 80 < ~/Desktop/Heart.jpg`

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work by using this command: nc -l -p 80 < ~/Desktop/Heart.jpg Then in a browser typing 192.168.88.221 and it opened the heart image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using this command: nc -l -p 80 < ~/Desktop/Heart.jpg Then in a browser typing 192.168.88.221 and it opened the heart image.

[Server Active And Connected On Port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Eaw.jpg)

Comment: Now try doing it a second time. (Or do you only want to "share" a single file once?)

Comment: What do you mean doing it a second time?

Comment: Clear browser cache, try to show the heart image a second time. (The point I'm trying to make: netcat by itself is not a very good html server).